# How do I set up network boot in Mythbuntu?

Tags: mythbuntu, mythtv

I would like to use MythTV frontend systems that have no local storage. How do I set them up to boot from a network drive (mythbuntu-diskless)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the necessary prerequisites.

**You have the following 2 options:**

- If you already have a DHCP server on your network do the following:

  `sudo apt-get install mythbuntu-diskless-server tftpd-hpa`
- If you do not have a DHCP server on your network do the following

  `sudo apt-get install mythbuntu-diskless-server-standalone tftpd-hpa`

**Edit the tftp configuration**

- `sudo vi /etc/default/tftpd-hpa`
- Edit the TFTP_DIRECTORY= to

  `TFTP_DIRECTORY="/var/lib/tftpboot/ltsp/i386"`
- Restart tftp

  `sudo service tftpd-hpa restart`

**Configure the overlay NFS export**

- `sudo dpkg-reconfigure mythbuntu-diskless-server`
- Answer yes to both questions

**Create the boot image**

- Check the following first

  `ltsp-build-client --extra-help`
- Start the image making

  `sudo ltsp-build-client --mythbuntu --mythbuntu-user-credentials="your-user-id-here:your-password-here"`
- For the credentials do not use "mythtv" it will already be created.
  Later we will setup mythtv ID to auto-login.
- This will install the image to /opt/ltsp/i386
- This will take awhile!

**Configure the DHCP server**

- For Untangle do the following
- Go to the Web UI for Untange, Config, Networking, Advanced, DHCP &
  DNS (from the dropdown). In the custom field box put

  `dhcp-boot=pxelinux.0,,X.X.X.X`
- Put the IP where you installed the diskless and tftpd packages
- For DD-WRT you should be able to do the following --- Untested
- Navigate to Admin>Services\
- Add the following for Additional DNS options:

  `dhcp-boot=/pxelinux.0,,X.X.X.X`
- Put the IP where you installed the diskless and tftpd packages
- For the mythbuntu-diskless-server-standalone package do the following
  --- Untested

  `sudo vi /etc/dhcp3.conf`
- Add the following lines:

  `allow booting;<br />allow bootp;<br />class "pxeclients" {<br />   match if substring(option vendor-class-identifier, 0, 9) = "PXEClient";<br />   next-server 192.168.1.100;<br />   filename "linux-install/pxelinux.0";<br />}`
- The **next-server** directive indicates the TFTP server that the
  system will contact. The filename is the init file that will be
  loaded to provide the bootloader. This example is specific to the
  Redhat and Fedora Core implementation and may vary depending on your
  distribution. //Alternative dhcp.conf, assume your PXE root is
  /mnt/pxe, and you assign your box a static IP of 192.168.1.60:

  `#option domain-name "domain";<br />default-lease-time 600;<br />max-lease-time 7200;<br />ddns-update-style ad-hoc;<br />subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {<br />   range 192.168.1.60 192.168.1.60;<br />   }<br />  option option-150 code 150 = text ; <br />   host mythtoo { <br />       hardware ethernet 00:14:2A:B3:E4:1C; <br />       option option-150 "/mnt/pxe/boot/grub.lst"; <br />       option routers 192.168.1.1;<br />       next-server 192.168.1.90;<br />       filename "/mnt/pxe/boot/pxegrub"; <br />       filename "/mnt/pxe/pxelinux.0";<br />   }`

**You can now boot your client**

- Any changes you make while your frontend is booted will be saved for
  only that fronend on the server under
  /var/cache/mythbuntu-diskless/overlay
- Updating Configs/Adding Packages To the boot image
- First mount /proc to the image

  `sudo mount -o bind /proc /opt/ltsp/i386/proc/`
- Switch to the image environment

  `sudo chroot /opt/ltsp/i386`
- Now do whatever you want as if you were on a frontend. Anything you
  do here will be done for all frontends that boot via the network

Somethings you can do

- Enable Mythbuntu repos

  `wget http://www.mythbuntu.org/files/mythbuntu-repos.deb`
  `dpkg -i mythbuntu-repos.deb`
  `dpkg-reconfigure mythbuntu-repos`
  `apt-get update`
  `apt-get upgrade`
- Configure Auto-Login

  `cd /etc/gdm`
  `vi custom.conf`
- Paste the following

  `[daemon]<br />DefaultSession=mythbuntu<br />TimedLoginEnable=false<br />AutomaticLoginEnable=true<br />TimedLogin=mythtv<br />AutomaticLogin=mythtv<br />TimedLoginDelay=0<br />`
- Configure frontend to connect to the backend for all frontends.

  `cd /etc/mythtv`
- Edit config.xml and mysql.txt

**NVIDA-Drivers**

- Blacklist nouveau

  `vi /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`
- Add the following to the end of the file

  `blacklist nouveau`
- Install Nvidia Drivers

  `apt-get install nvidia-common`
  `apt-get install nvidia-current`
- Go to Nvidia's website get the link for the current nvidia drivers.
  Use wget to save it somewhere (I used /home/mythtv)
- Continued after booting frontend
- When done making changes do

  `exit`
  `sudo umount /opt/ltsp/i386/proc`
  `sudo ltsp-update-image`
- Remove Overlays for frontends already booted -**IF NEEDED or WHEN YOU
  WANT TO**
- Note this will remove all settings you made to your frontend when it
  was booted

  `cd /var/cache/mythbuntu-diskless/overlay`
  `sudo rm -fr *`

NVIDIA-Drivers Final

- Boot frontend

  `CTRL-ALT-F1`
- Login

  `sudo service gdm stop`
  `sudo sh ./PATH_TO_DOWNLOADED_NVIDIA_DRIVERS`
  `sudo service gdm start`
- To enable sound via HDMI
- Open Terminal

  `alsamixer`
- Unmute the SPIF outputs to enable sound via HDMI

Comment: I've had real trouble with the 'mythbuntu' switches under Ubuntu/Mythbuntu 11.10 and the fat-client build also requires you to patch some files Ref: http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ltsp-upstream/ltsp/ltsp-trunk/revision/1944 (Note Ubuntu 12.04 these patches have been added and fat-client will work, mythbuntu options on the ltsp-build may still be broken though).